# Facebook user has no avatar, but the default blank avatar isn't showing either in my web app

Tags: facebook, avatar

I have a Facebook application and I show showing Facebook Connected users on my pages.

But I see this particular user's avatar is just blank. However Facebook's own "no photo" image is not showing either as well as it's "f" logo in the bottom right.

Can't get why it's so weird and is there any way to determine such users?

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: @bakytn, this site is for programming questions, so please find another source of wisdom.

Comment: This seems programming related, the OP seems to have programmed a facebook app which isn't showing avators

Comment: @Gamecat, @Richard, this IS programming related. And I know what is this site for, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Facebook's own avatar is also not showing, its a bug/issue with facebook itself and not something related to your application. I would suggest reporting this to Facebook as a bug and then waiting for them to fix it.

Edit: The issue seems to be that the user tried to upload an image, but the file got corrupted during the upload and now its showing the broken image icon. Just ask the user to re-upload his image, most likely that would fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's unusual situation so I can treat it as an exception. I think I will follow your suggestions. THanks again!

Comment: yes yes :) I did .. it just says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"